# Expression Tree Serializer

Tags: c#, wcf, linq, serialization

I want to use Linq Expressions on Client Side, Serialize them and Execute them on server Side.

For this I want to use: http://expressiontree.codeplex.com/

But I want to Execute them agains a own WCF Call.

That means i Have a Call on WCf Side:

```
ImageDTO[] GetImages(XElement exp);
```

I now want to have a IQueryable on Client Side (on which I can execute Linq Expressions), and I have a IQueryable on Serverside (from my data acess layer, on wich i want to execute the serialized expression).

But I'm not sure how to do this, and I don't find any Examples...

On Client Side i think I should implement Query in a Class, this class I tell in the Constructor to use my implementation of QueryProvider (from where I call the WCF Service). But I'm not sure if this is correct...

Maybe someone can help with a Example.

Comment: I know this is not an answer to your question, but from experience, I would not do this and instead write dedicated business services. You add complexity, and allow your clients to bring the system down with bad queries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's an implementation of `IQueryable<T>` in the framework - [`MSDN: EnumerableQuery<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc190116.aspx)

If you can use this on the client to build the query, you can get the whole Expression Tree from the `IQueryable<T>.Expression` property.

You'll have to test this to see if it works with that Expression Tree Serializer.

```
var iQueryable = new EnumerableQuery<Model>( Enumerable.Empty<Model>() );

var query = iQueryable.Include( ... ).Where( ... ).OrderBy( ... );

var expressionTree = query.Expression;
```

You can then serialize the expression, squirt it accross the wire and then deserialize it.

---

Then the problem is that the expression tree is based on an `EnumerableQuery<T>`.

So you need to replace that with your `IQueryable<T>` source from your real `DbContext`

This gets a *bit* messy, but I've written an implementation using an `ExpressionVisitor:`

```
IQueryable FixupExpressionTree( ObjectContext ctx, Type entityType, Expression expression )
{
    var tObjectContext = ctx.GetType();
    var mCreateObjectSetOpen = tObjectContext.GetMethod( "CreateObjectSet", new Type[ 0 ] );
    var mCreateObjectSetClosed = mCreateObjectSetOpen.MakeGenericMethod( entityType );

    var objectQuery = ( ObjectQuery ) mCreateObjectSetClosed.Invoke( ctx, null );

    var eFixed = new Visitor( objectQuery, entityType ).Visit( expression );

    var qFixed = ( ( IQueryable ) objectQuery ).Provider.CreateQuery( eFixed );

    return qFixed;
}
```

and the `ExpressionVisitor` itself:

```
public class Visitor : ExpressionVisitor
{
    ObjectQuery _Source = null;
    Type _EntityType = null;

    public Visitor( ObjectQuery source, Type entityType ) { _Source = source; _EntityType = entityType; }

    protected override Expression VisitConstant( ConstantExpression node )
    {
        if ( !node.Type.Name.Contains( "EnumerableQuery" ) ) return base.VisitConstant( node );

        var eConstantInstance = Expression.Constant( _Source );
        var eConstantArgument = Expression.Constant( MergeOption.AppendOnly );

        var tObjectQueryOpen = typeof( ObjectQuery<> );
        var tObjectQueryClosed = tObjectQueryOpen.MakeGenericType( _EntityType );
        var eMergeAsMethod = tObjectQueryClosed.GetMethod( "MergeAs", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic );

        return Expression.Call( eConstantInstance, eMergeAsMethod, eConstantArgument );
    }
}
```

Calling this is straight forward:

```
Type entityType = ...
Expression expression = ...
DbContext db = ...

ObjectContext ctx = ( ( IObjectContextAdapter ) db ).ObjectContext;

IQueryable query = FixupExpressionTree( ctx, entityType, expression );
```

Comment: Okay, and when I serialised the Expression, and Deserialised on the Server, how do i execute it against my IQueryable wich I have from my DL Layer?

Comment: Jochen:  YourIQueryable.Provider.CreateQuery<Model>(receivedExpression).ToList()

Comment: @JochenKühner Sorry for the delay. I've updated my post to answer your comment.

Comment: I think this could work on my System, but I now solved it using Interlinq. But I mark this as the answer

Comment: @JochenKühner it would be helpful to promote your answer (to an actual answer) for helping others see.  InterLinq looks like a very good answer to your problem.

Answer (score 1):

To Solve my Problem, I used Interlinq, but a Version wich I forked, so that it also works with Silverlight.

https://github.com/jogibear9988/Interlinq-2