# Generate queries on the client side

Tags: c#, sql, linq, ado.net

I want to be able to generate the queries on the client side and then send them to the server. In order to still have security this is my approach:

1. Every client is associated to an account. So the client will have to send the server the account id and query.
2. Server will then receive the account id and query. **Server will then perform a join of all the tables and rows that are related to that account**.
3. Once server has all records related to that account as a join statement. Then it will execute the query the client sent and will execute that query against the join not the whole database.

**So my question is how can I send a linq query to a server?** For example I will like the client to send:

```
//           Id of Account                  QUERY
object[]{ "AfKX-3451-X4hT-...", myContext.Customers.Where(x=>x.Age>18) }
```

The second parameter is of type IQueryable therefore I cannot serialize it :(

*If a malicious user decompiles client application and alters the queries then he will only affect his account and not the whole database.*

Comment: Are you going to have a copy of your EF model locally?

Comment: This sounds like a vary bad idea. Not only because *anyone* could decompile the application, but mainly because it will pull all business logic into the client. When a client can only get or save granular data there can hardly be be any server/service-side business logic. But anyway, it looks like OData would be a much better option to achieve this (depending on the kind of application you're talking about). Also, if this is about multi tenancy, there are better ways to deal with that in EF (e.g. a schema per tenant).

Answer (score 2):

I recommend exposing an OData endpoint and use Linq to query it.
For more information: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee622463.aspx

Comment: i think .net odata implemention is not ready for now but its powerful. your choice

Answer (score 1):

You can serialize the second parameter via expression tree serializer libraries or else you can find serializer in entity framework's source code. call web serive with user id and serialized query and add some criteria to query like a query = query.Where(f=>f.UserId==userId) and execute it.

[Expression Tree Serializer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15887797/expression-tree-serializer)

You must return a known type for all search result like a datatable, datarow...  you can implement your own.

In addition you can use 3rd party components to do this for example telerik's filter control.